# OW TO ADD COLOR to confusion martix?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, metrics

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predicted = model.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(label_test,predicted.round()))

HOW TO ADD COLOR to confusion metrics in that code ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use : `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html
or `sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay¶` depending of your version : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay

Comment: Thanks, but what i mean is how edit this code to print woth colors ? what should i add

Comment: Just to be sure your output is : 
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2]])

Comment: THANKS , my out but is a positive or negative text